# Backing up file moves with rsync + tar

Tags: backup, rsync, mount, tar

I have a mirroring system in place with rsync and it works well. However, moving a file causes it to be transferred again in its entirety.

Given what I know about the rsync algorithm's rolling checksum, wouldn't it be possible to:

1. tar all the source files
2. rsync the tar

and only incur a block-size penalty for the change in file name, after which the checksum would resynchronise? However, i don't have the temporary spool space for a large .tar file.

My questions:

Is there an efficient, read/write way to mount a filesystem as a tar, which i can rsync?

Is there a way of piping tar | rsync in some way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: try tu use avfs virtual filesystem

Comment: Checkout http://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gzip` instead of `tar`, there is the `rsyncable` option.

`Gzip` the source, then use `rsync` to copy it to the destination. Each night, update the gzip archive, and use `rsync` again. `rsyncable` will update the gzip archive in such a way that it will comply with rsync's update algorithm and only the changed parts within the gzip archive are sync'ed across each night, not the whole archive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - but as per the question i don't have the spool space for a temporary file (the volume to sync is multiple terabytes). As of this comment i still don't have a good solution (but i'm now considering rsync'ing the block device directly)